# How to add button to row of JTable?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable

I have a Swing based application containing a `JTable`. Now I would like to allow each row to be updated or deleted, using a unique row ID. So I want to add an update and delete button to each row, which have the capability to support an ActionListener. However, I have no idea how to do this using NetBeans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display a button in a column you need to create:

1. a custom renderer to display the JButton
2. a custom editor to respond to the mouse click

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html). The section on:

1. `Using Custom Renders` will explain the basics of using a renderer
2. `Using Other Editors` will explain the basics of using an editor

Working example are provided in the tutorial that you can download.

You can check out [Table Button Column](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/) for one approach.

The code uses a single class to implement the custom renderer and editor that you will need for the column to display your text as a button.