# Is there a Java Swing component similar to "..."-Buttons in PL/SQL Developer?

Tags: java, swing, button, plsql, jtable

I want to add a button to my JTable. When this button is clicked, the contents of the corresponding cell should be shown in a new JTextArea. In PL/SQL Developer there is such a button, as you can see here:

Clickable :

[image]

Edit: I tried it like this:

```
public class TestKonfigTableCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

@Override
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
        int row, int column) {

    JLabel l = (JLabel) super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
    JButton openButton = new JButton("...");
    l.add(openButton);

    return l;
    }
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work. What did I do wrong ?

Comment: Why can't you use a normal JButton?

Comment: Is that possible ? Where would be the best place to add that button ? In the table model ? In a custom cell renderer ? Or somewhere else ?

Comment: `new JButton("...")` inside your `TableCellRenderer`

Comment: JButton with custom image: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25959069/how-to-add-button-to-row-of-jtable

Answer (score 2):

If by "it does not seem to work", you mean you cannot click on the button, that is to be expected.

The component returned by the renderer is not added to the Swing hierarchy. Instead, only its painted representation is used in the table for performance reasons. That is the reason a typical renderer always returns the same component after updating its state. See the ["Concept: renderers and editors" section](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) in the `JTable` tutorial for more information.

There are a number of posts available on how to include a clickable button in a `JTable`. For example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25959069/how-to-add-button-to-row-of-jtable).